# Creating website for stocks info and charts using APIs and Java and Postman

Tags: java, python, html, rest, postman-testcase

I want to create website that show stocks information using something like this:
https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/yahoo-finance1/tutorials/build-your-own-stock-charts-with-yahoo-finance-api-and-python

Can I use Postman and how do I Java to send the information and to build the charts on to my website?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @CryptoAngel , you should definitely do this.  It will be awesome.
Please let  us all know how it's going.